# In SQL can you set 1 Variable with multiple values to Create multiple users?

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql, variables

I'm wondering if a simple and quick T-SQL script can be made for editing a DB to create users, that's efficient for different people to use. My example would mean looping through a variable getting different values each time.

For example I would like the below to:

1. Use the DB DBNAME1
2. Declare @User, with multiple Users
3. Create a SQL commands to run (i.e. Create a User and apply their role)
4. Only apply them if the the user does not exist

This is an example script which works if I am adding 1 user, but I would like to add more than one user with this simplified version or similar, so people only have to add a list of names in 1 area?

```
USE DBNAME1
GO
Declare @User NVARCHAR (30) = 'Domain\Username1', 'Domain\Username2', 'Domain\Username3' etc.

Declare @CMD NVARCHAR (90) = 'CREATE USER "' + @User +'" FOR LOGIN "' + @User + '"'
Declare @CMD2 NVARCHAR (90) ='ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [' + @User + ']'

if not exists(select name from sys.database_principals where name = @User)
    Begin   exec(@cmd) exec(@cmd2)  End
        ELSE
    Begin   Print '['+ @User +'] Exists'    END
```

The above as it is give an error below of:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'domain\Username2'.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@User".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@User".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@User".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@cmd".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@cmd2".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 11
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@User".

Is something like this possible, as it would make things a lot nicer to work with?

Comment: Insert those users into table, then go one by one and assign it's value to variable and do your dynamic sql, that's one of the way how you can do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a table variable to store usernames.

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE(Username VARCHAR(64))

INSERT INTO @Users(Username) VALUES('Domain\Username1')
INSERT INTO @Users(Username) VALUES('Domain\Username2')

DECLARE @Username AS VARCHAR(64)

DECLARE C_Users CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Username FROM @Users

OPEN C_Users
FETCH NEXT FROM C_Users INTO @Username

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = @Username)
    BEGIN
        EXEC('CREATE USER [' + @Username + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @Username + ']')
        EXEC('ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [' + @Username + ']')
        PRINT '['+ @Username +'] created'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT '['+ @Username +'] already exists'
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_Users INTO @Username

END

CLOSE C_Users
DEALLOCATE C_Users
```

Comment: I would still prefer to build the sql in a variable, makes it easier to `print` them for debug.